# Why does React Native even updated in the latest version present a build error in Windows 11?

Tags: react-native

I'm having the error below when trying to build my app in React Native, I've already updated all the dependencies, checked the environment configuration, checked the Android SDK, updated Gradle and still my app doesn't run. I haven't even started writing the code and I'm already unimpressed. Can any of you help me solve this?
I uploaded it to GitHub, if you can test it on your machine and help me solve it I would be very grateful, follow the repository link: https://github.com/eujennifferlino/SpaceQuad

ERRO APRESENTADO[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Swg.png)

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect' (type 'ListingFileRedirectTask').

  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ListingFileRedirectTask' property 'listingFile' specifies file 'C:\Projetos\SpaceQuad\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json' which doesn't exist.

    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
    2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist for more details about this problem.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

```
at makeError (C:\Projetos\SpaceQuad\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Projetos\SpaceQuad\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Projetos\SpaceQuad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Projetos\SpaceQuad\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

I updated all the dependencies, cleared the cache, deleted the '.gradle' file and redid, but nothing works

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.